# Use tablediff.exe to compare two tables and update another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to Compare let's say table A and B. I'm configuring the tablediff.exe so that the table A is the source and the table B is the destination. By default the sql script file generated by the tablediff.exe is pointing to the destination table.

for an example:
 if the table A has an extra row compared to the table B. Script file should have something like this.

```
INSERT INTO B VALUES (......)
```

what i want is to change the table name in the script file.so that the result would be like this.

```
INSERT INTO C VALUES (......)
```

is there anyway i could do this by passing some argument to the tablediff.exe rather than editing the sql script file manually ?

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TableDiff will compare `source` and `destination` tables and either provide your the differences in a `file` or create a `table` with differences. You need to change your script manually to change the destination table name for your requirement. Please refer to [TableDiff](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843.aspx) MSDN link and [Simple Talk](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/sql-tools/sql-server-tablediff-utility/) link for information.